# How thread-safe is a JOOQ Configuration with a DataSourceConnectionProvider?

Tags: jooq

I tend to write my database classes using the following pattern:

```
public class AccountDao { 
    private final Configuration configuration;

    @Inject
    public AccountDao(final @Named(ACCOUNT_DATA_SOURCE) DataSource dataSource) {
        configuration = new DefaultConfiguration().derive(dataSource).derive(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
    }

    private UserRecord getUserById(final UUID id) {
        return using(configuration)
            .selectFrom(USER)
            .where(USER.ID.eq(id))
            .fetchOne();
    }
  
    ...
```

If I create a second class that also needs to use JOOQ code to connect to the same database, at what level should I share the connection? Can I create a second `Configuration` using the same DataSource, or might that cause concurrency issues?

Comment: Checkout https://blog.jooq.org/tag/cdi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Configuration` contains caches, such as reflection caches, which you should not re-create every time. Ideally, you have a single `Configuration` for your `DataSource`, which you're sharing everywhere and injecting from your CDI setup. Spring Boot does that automatically for you. I'm not aware of any CDI/jOOQ auto configuration, but you can easily roll your own.

There's no thread safety guarantee, because a `Configuration` is just a collection of settings and SPI implementations, among which the `ConnectionProvider`. If your hand-rolled `ConnectionProvider` isn't thread safe, then your `Configuration` isn't, either. If you're using the `DataSourceConnectionProvider` as in your example, then the thread safety guarantees of your `DataSource` are inherited. In classic Spring / Java EE setups, a `DataSource` is usually thread-bound, allowing for AOP oriented transaction declarations, so you'll be safe injecting that instance everywhere (since you're already injecting the `DataSource`)

It's all documented here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/thread-safety/

> `org.jooq.Configuration`, and by consequence `org.jooq.DSLContext`, make no thread safety guarantees, but by carefully observing a few rules, they can be shared in a thread safe way. We encourage sharing `Configuration` instances, because they contain caches for work not worth repeating, such as reflection field and method lookups for `org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper`. If you're using Spring or CDI for dependency injection, you will want to be able to inject a `DSLContext` instance everywhere you use it.